# LeetCode: Stone Game C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, recursion, dynamic-programming

https://leetcode.com/problems/stone-game/

> Alex and Lee play a game with piles of stones.  There are an even
> number of piles arranged in a row, and each pile has a positive
> integer number of stones piles[i].
>
> The objective of the game is to end with the most stones.  The total
> number of stones is odd, so there are no ties.
>
> Alex and Lee take turns, with Alex starting first.  Each turn, a
> player takes the entire pile of stones from either the beginning or
> the end of the row.  This continues until there are no more piles
> left, at which point the person with the most stones wins.
>
> Assuming Alex and Lee play optimally, return True if and only if Alex
> wins the game.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: piles = [5,3,4,5] Output: true Explanation:  Alex starts first,
> and can only take the first 5 or the last 5. Say he takes the first 5,
> so that the row becomes [3, 4, 5]. If Lee takes 3, then the board is
> [4, 5], and Alex takes 5 to win with 10 points. If Lee takes the last
> 5, then the board is [3, 4], and Alex takes 4 to win with 9 points.
> This demonstrated that taking the first 5 was a winning move for Alex,
> so we return true.
>
> Constraints:
>
> 2 <= piles.length <= 500 piles.length is even. 1 <= piles[i] <= 500
> sum(piles) is odd.

I am working on my recursion an dynamic programming skills. please review for performance

solution 1: recursion

```cs
public bool StoneGame(int[] piles)
{
    return Helper(piles, 0, piles.Length - 1, 0, 0, true);
}

private bool Helper(int[] piles, int start, int end, int sumAlex, int sumLee, bool isAlex)
{
    if (start >= end)
    {
        return sumAlex > sumLee;
    }
    if (isAlex)
    {
        return Helper(piles, start + 1, end, sumAlex + piles[start], sumLee, false)
               || Helper(piles, start, end - 1, sumAlex + piles[end], sumLee, false);
    }
    else
    {
        return Helper(piles, start + 1, end, sumAlex, sumLee + piles[start], true)
               || Helper(piles, start, end - 1, sumAlex, sumLee + piles[end], true);
    }
}
```

Solution 2: DP

```cs
public class Solution
{
    private int[,] dp;
    public bool StoneGame3(int[] piles)
    {
        dp = new int[piles.Length, piles.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < piles.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < piles.Length; j++)
            {
                dp[i, j] = -1;
            }
        }
        //begin or end of the row
        int s = 0;
        int e = piles.Length - 1;
        Helper(s, e, true, piles);
        return dp[0, piles.Length - 1] > 0;
    }

    private int Helper(int s, int e, bool isAlex, int[] piles)
    {
        if (s > e)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (s == e)
        {
            return piles[s];
        }

        if (dp[s, e] != -1)
        {
            return dp[s, e];
        }

        if (isAlex)
        {
            dp[s, e] = Math.Max(piles[s] + Helper(s + 1, e, !isAlex, piles), piles[e] + Helper(s, e - 1, !isAlex, piles));
        }
        else
        {
            //we remove what lee is picking and we will take the min so we will have the max stones for alex
            dp[s, e] = Math.Min(-piles[s] + Helper(s + 1, e, !isAlex, piles), -piles[e] + Helper(s, e - 1, !isAlex, piles));
        }
        return dp[s, e];
    }
}
```